# equijoins on schema PCollections - not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to join two PCollection transactions and reviews as below as per the apache beam documentation (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms)

```
PCollection<Transaction> transactions = readTransactions();
PCollection<Review> reviews = readReviews();
PCollection<Row> joined = transactions.apply(
Join.innerJoin(reviews).using("userId", "productId"));
```

But I am getting compilations error like apply needs
apply(PTransform<? super PCollection, OutputT> t)

Is the code snippet in the document correct way of joining? Please help?

Comment: From the code you provided I can not see any problems. If you could provide some more information I may be able to help you. How is transactions and reviews generated? And what is the package name for the Join class? Is it org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms? What version of Apache Beam are you using?

Comment: beam version - 2.25.0
transactions and reviews are two Model classes. I am generating Pcollection of transaction and reviews using Pardo from the source.
Join class Is imporing from package org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms
What ever datatype i used (like TableRow or String) i am getting this error

Comment: Could you provide the code of your program that we can run and try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It would also help to provide a more descriptive error message if possible. It's difficult to tell which line the error message you quoted is referring to without a stack trace, for example. Reading the documentation for Join, it looks like it requires two schema PCollections. So a good first step is to check that both transactions and reviews are schema PCollections.